# Replotting a closed figure from command line in Python without re-executing code

Tags: python

I wrote a simple Python code to plot a signal. File is called signal.py

```
samples=np.arange(t*fs)/fs
signal=np.sin(2*np.pi*f*samples)
signal*=32767
signal=np.int16(signal)
wavfile.write(input("Name your file: "),fs,signal)
plt.plot(signal)
plt.show()
```

When called in cmd line,

*python signal.py*

The code runs. I can see the plot. All is well. But after i close the plot, without re-running the code, is it possible to plot ONLY the signal again, as if all the variables were stored in a workspace of sort , similar to MATLAB.

i tried >> *plt.plot(signal)*

*'plt.plot' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file*.

Or maybe the question should be , if its possible to store the variables in a workspace from where you can call and plot the variables ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this is not the perfect answer, the closest workaround I have come to find is

run the python shell in cmd,

> ```
> python
> import signal
> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
> plt.plot(signal.signal)
> plt.show()
> ```

After this i can close the figure and run just the last 2 lines to re-open the figure.

Comment: Did the command `python -i signal.py` not work? The idea was that in the REPL after the script ran, you could just type `plt.plot(signal); plt.show()`, no need to `import signal` in that case.

Comment: @BatWannaBe that command seems to run the whole code again. I have a few prompts before the above shown code. So it calls all the prompts again. I wanted to avoid having to input the prompts again.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by prompt because you hadn't posted it, but if you mean Python code, the typical way to only run some code when you want is to structure it into functions. When you run the script, the function are defined but do not run. You then have the freedom to call functions in the REPL when you want.

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about a REPL aka language shell. There are many options for Python, and these are often bundled with IDEs so you can write your script and run it side-to-side. A common example is the *Spyder* IDE that uses the *IPython* shell.

IDEs are far more convenient, but CPython already comes with a simple REPL called the "interactive mode" you can start from the command line. You can enter it directly with the command `python`, or you can run your script first then enter it `python -i signal.py`. Type `exit()` to exit interactive mode.